# how to remove "debug" from apk?

Tags: android, apk

how remove "debug" from app name ?
i use this code in build.gradle :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'My Body' }
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName " + "V." + defaultConfig.versionName)
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
        }
        debug {}
    }
```

but output file name = "My Body V.1.0debug.apk"
i need this = "My Body V.1.0.apk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to open the Build Variants window. You can do this by hovering the mouse of the icon in the lower left corner of Android Studio and selecting Build Variants. Then to the right of the app module, click on "debug" and select "release" from the drop down list. Android Studio will now generate a release APK that does not have "debug" in the name.

Note that you will also need to create a keystore so that you can sign your app. Then you will need to configure Android Studio to use your keystore. See [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) for more details about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Debug apk and `Release apk` are different things. You have to generate a `signed apk` to release your app on `Google Play`.

```
Build > Generate Signed Apk
```

Gradle:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
```